# Making an element saved and then recovered from the disk draggable and resizable again

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a DIV that I've made draggable and resizable.  Next I use Ajax to store the HTML for the DIV  on the disk, including all the handles and class flags that jQuery-UI created for it.  Then I exit the page and reaccess it with the browser, coming in to a clean, fresh screen presented by the site. And now I'd like to read the stored HTML back down from the disk and append it to the main wrapper to recreate the original draggable/resizable DIV  that was on the page.

The DIV comes down fine with all the handles and class flags that jQuery-UI created for it, but it's not draggable or resizable. So apparently when you call draggable() or resizable() jQuery-UI does more than just create those handles and flags.

Does someone have a feel for what's going on here and what I need to do to make the stored DIV resizable and draggable again when it's brought back from the disk appended back on the page?

Thanks

Comment: When you call draggable/resizable, jquery adds event handlers and everything to the element so that it is draggable. you need to call those functions again to make them draggable/resizable

Comment: Yes, I was afraid of that.  And I should probably destroy the draggable and resizable setup currently on the DIV before I do the disk store,  to avoid confusion with the old flags and handles when I re-issue draggable and resizable on the recovered DIV.

Comment: you could if you want, although I don't think it'd matter. additionally you could store the current position of the divs to recreate the user interface

Comment: out of curiousity are you building some sort of editor

Comment: "you could store the current position of the divs to recreate the user interface"  Yes, the position and all the style parameters are saved and come back fine, so the restored DIV looks just like the original. I just can't drag or resize it (yet). "Out of curiousity are you building some sort of editor?"  Yes.  It creates web pages.